# Uno imprime y el otro no PHP

Tags: php, select, post

Lo que tengo que hacer es insertar estadias o asistencia para cada persona donde cada dia puede estar en un lugar (frente de trabajo) diferente.

Por eso hice esa especie de planilla llena de *selects* en donde el usuario selecciona una opción en un dia para un empleado y el resto del mes se le rellena con el valor seleccionado.

Por ejemplo, Juan Perez estuvo desde el 13 del mes en adelante en P1, entonces selecciono P1 en el 13 del mes y el resto del mes se le rellena con P1.
Así para todos los empleados.

Entonces al final mando este `form` a otro php donde se Insertan los registros en una tabla de MySql.

El tema es que de esos 119 empleados, solo pasan 31 creo, el resto de los valores ( frentes de trabajo) no pasan al otro PHP, tal como se ve en la cuarta imagen, donde i = 31 & j = 5 (`select name ='x31x5'`).

**Código desde donde nacen los SELECT:**

```
<form action="estadia3.php" method="POST">

<?php
$fechaaa = $_POST['fechita'];
$fecha = strtotime($fechaaa);
$anio = date("Y", $fecha);  //2020
$mes = date("m", $fecha);   //01 si enero con 31 dias
$cantidad = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $mes, $anio);
echo "<input type='hidden' name='cantidad' id='cantidad' value ='". $cantidad ."'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='mes' id='mes' value ='". $mes ."'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='anio' id='anio' value ='". $anio ."'>";

$sql2 = "SELECT `ID_EMP`, `NOMBRE`, `PRI_APELLIDO`, `SEG_APELLIDO` FROM `personal` WHERE ID_EMP <> 123 AND ID_EMP <> 124 AND ID_EMP <> 125 AND ID_EMP <> 126 AND ID_EMP <> 127 AND ID_EMP <> 128 AND ID_EMP <> 129 AND ID_EMP <> 130 AND ID_EMP <> 131 AND ID_EMP <> 132 ORDER BY PRI_APELLIDO;";
$result2 = $conexion->query($sql2);
if ($result2->num_rows > 0) //si la variable tiene al menos 1 fila entonces seguimos con el codigo
{
    $input = array();
    while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        array_push($input, "<br><input type='text' value = '".$row2['NOMBRE']." ".$row2['PRI_APELLIDO']." ".$row2['SEG_APELLIDO']."' readonly name='".$row2['ID_EMP']."' class = 'name'>");         
    }
}
else{
    echo "No hubo resultados";
}

$sql3 = "SELECT `ID_FRENTE`, `SIGLA` FROM `frente_trabajo`";
$result3 = $conexion->query($sql3);

if ($result3->num_rows > 0) //si la variable tiene al menos 1 fila entonces seguimos con el codigo
{
    $combobit3="";//"<option value='' selected disabled hidden></option>";
    while ($row3 = $result3 ->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $combobit3 .=" <option value='".$row3['ID_FRENTE']."'>".$row3['SIGLA']."</option>";
    }
}
else{
    echo "No hubo resultados";
}

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `personal` WHERE ID_EMP <> 123 AND ID_EMP <> 124 AND ID_EMP <> 125 AND ID_EMP <> 126 AND ID_EMP <> 127 AND ID_EMP <> 128 AND ID_EMP <> 129 AND ID_EMP <> 130 AND ID_EMP <> 131 AND ID_EMP <> 132;";
$result = $conexion->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) //si la variable tiene al menos 1 fila entonces seguimos con el codigo
{
    if ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $count =$row['COUNT(*)']; //119
        $count = ($count - 1); //empleados. excluye pidencos y externos119
        echo "<input type='hidden' name ='count' id='count' value ='". $count ."'>";
    }
}
else{
    echo "No hubo resultados";
}
for ($i=1; $i <=$cantidad+1 ; $i++) { 
    if ($i==1) {
        echo "<input type='text' value = '-NOMBRE-' readonly class = 'name'> ";
    }else{
        echo "<input type = 'text' value= '".($i-1)."' readonly class='dia'>";
    }
}
for ($i=0; $i <=$count ; $i++) { 
    for ($j=1; $j <=$cantidad+1 ; $j++) { 
        if ($j==1) {
            echo $input[$i];
        }else{
            echo "<select name='x".$i."x".($j-1)."' class ='dia' id='x".$i."x".($j-1)."' onchange='cambia(this)' >". $combobit3." </select>";
        }
    }
}
?>
<br>
<button type="submit" class="saveBtn">GUARDAR</button><br>
</form>
```

**Código para procesamiento e INSERTS:**

```
<?php
require ("conec.php");
$conexion = conecta();

$count = $_POST['count']; // numero de empleados menos los especiales
$cantidad = $_POST['cantidad']; // dias del mes
$mes = $_POST['mes'];
$anio = $_POST['anio'];
$i = 0;
$sql2 = "SELECT `ID_EMP` FROM `personal` WHERE ID_EMP <> 123 AND ID_EMP <> 124 AND ID_EMP <> 125 AND ID_EMP <> 126 AND ID_EMP <> 127 AND ID_EMP <> 128 AND ID_EMP <> 129 AND ID_EMP <> 130 AND ID_EMP <> 131 AND ID_EMP <> 132;"; //empleados especiales
$result2 = $conexion->query($sql2);
if ($result2->num_rows > 0){ 
     //0 es la ROW  
    while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) AND $i != $count){
        for ($j=1; $j <= ($cantidad) ; $j++) { // J SON LOS DIAS
            $diaFrente = "x" . $i . "x" . $j ;
            $frente = $_POST[$diaFrente];
            $fecha = $anio."-".$mes."-".$j;
            $emp = $row2['ID_EMP'];
            echo "empleado: ".$emp;
            $sqlx = "INSERT INTO `estadia` ( `ID_EMPLEADO`, `ID_FRENTE`, `FECHA`) VALUES ( $emp, $frente ,'$fecha')";
            if(mysqli_query($conexion,$sqlx)){
                echo "ESTADIA CREADA <br>";
            }else{
                echo "Error: " . $sqlx . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conexion);echo "<br>";
            }//FIN else

        } //fin for

    $i++;
}//fin while
} //fin if
else{
    echo "No hubo resultados";
}

?>
```

**Función para llenar valores:**

```
function cambia(arg){
        var cantidad = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;
        var id = arg.getAttribute('id');
        var Aid = id.split("x");
        var numx = Aid[2];
        numx = parseInt(numx);
        for (var i = numx; i <= cantidad; i++) {
                var newid = "x" + Aid[1] + "x"+ i; //misma id pero +1
               var val = document.getElementById(id).value;
               document.getElementById(newid).value = val;
        }
}
```

[image: x4]

[image: x5]
[image: pruebaInsert]
[image: html]
[image: x]

Comment: ¿Cómo envías el formulario? Es decir, el fallo podría ser como estás enviado la selección de los select, que quizás estés enviando el resultado de uno y no del otro.

Comment: @mrddr pasa que tengo unos for para insertar a mysql. Todos funcionan  bien hasta que llega al x31x5.
Parte desde x1x1.

Comment: Algo en lo que estás haciendo no envía el resultado de ese select a tu script de PHP, si todos funcionan igual revisa que no se te haya escapado algo en la parte de HTML o que ese select esté en el mismo bloque que los anteriores.

Comment: adjunté una nueva captura donde se ve que el HTML esta aparentemente bien. Son mas de 100 select antes de ese y por alguna razon cuando llega ahi falla.

Comment: El error que te está dando es un error de sintaxis de SQL, ¿has comprobado si puede ser eso lo que está pasando? Tiene toda la pinta de que o bien no está recibiendo algún valor en concreto 'numero',nada,'fecha' (VALUES(34, ,'2020-01-5')) o te has olvidado de ponerlo.

Comment: el error de SQL es porque no puedo insertar NULL en la columna FRENTE, lo lanza porque claro, a FRENTE no llega nada en ese punto, pero en los anteriores, si te fijas bien, imprime frente: 1, frente: 1, frente: 1, frente: 1 hasta que llega a x31x5  y frente : NADA

Comment: ¿Cómo realizas el envío del formulario? o si no lo haces mediante formulario ¿cómo haces para enviar los resultados de todos los select/inputs a tu script PHP?

Comment: podrías ser un poco más explícito en tu pregunta? pon más código, cómo construyes esos select y de dónde viene toda información para saber qué podría estar pasando

Comment: Falta información. De dónde sale `$frente` en la variable PHP que, supongo, es la que usas para construir la consulta? Está llegando vacía, **suponemos** (porque tu pregunta está incompleta)

Comment: Lo siento, ahi esta el codigo

Comment: ¿Seleccionas algún valor en el `select x31x5` cuando envías el formulario?

Comment: @mrddr se selecciona de la misma manera que los anteriores, mediante una funcion dew javascript. Lo adjuntare arriba.
Aun dandole valor manualmente a esa casilla en particular, no funciona.
Aun iniciando el for de los INSERT en un valor cercano al del error no funciona.

Comment: No existe un limite de datos que se pueden enviar en un FORM? es lo unico que se me ocurre ahora.

Comment: Leí la pregunta y los comentarios, pero no logro entender cuál es el problema en sí ni dónde falla el código. Ayudaría mucho si explicas de entrada el problema, para saber luego dónde hay que analizar.

Comment: @A.Cedano el codigo lo que hace es generar algo como una hoja de excel con todos los nombres y un select x dia del mes para cada nombre.
Al pasar al PHP del action del form, solo detecta el frente (value de los select) de todos hasta el select x31x4, desde el x31x5 en adelante no lo recibe y no entiendo por que.

Comment: Por favor pulsa en [edit]  y explica **lo que quieres hacer**, no lo que estás haciendo. Son dos cosas distintas, lo que estás haciendo puede que esté mal (de hecho no funciona), entonces, de nada sirve que empieces a decir *tengo dos `for` tengo esto, tengo lo otro*. En problemas como este lo más importante es entender a qué quieres llegar. Entonces nosotros quizá te ayudaremos a optimizar corregir, etc. Te diremos quizá, ¿para qué tienes dos `for` o 5 `for`, si es mejor hacer esto o aquello?. Pero si no entendemos a qué quieres llegar es mucho más complicado ayudarte. No sé si me entiendes.

Comment: Este párrafo, donde intentas explicar el problema: *«Tengo ese codigo para sacar los valores de un select desde un form por POST. Todos los insert funcionan hasta que llega a x31x5. Cuando pongo mes febrero, al ser 29 dias el problema tambien ocurre pero en otro numero. COUNT son los empleados (119) excluyendo algunos especiales. CANTIDAD son los dias del mes que se selecciona.»*  es claro para ti que estás haciendo el programa, pero para nosotros es como leer en chino. Eso tienes que explicarlo con claridad si hiciera falta, pero lo más importante quizá es que expliques qué resultado esperas.

Comment: @A.Cedano Ahora intente explicar lo que queria hacer, ¿se entiende?, espero que si.

Comment: Un `print_r($POST);` te puede aclarar dudas sobre qué está recibiendo el script que construye los insert.

Answer (score 2):

Finalmente encontre el problema, es la cantidad de valores que pasan por el `POST`.
¿Como lo supe?, con este codigo:

```
foreach($_POST as $campo => $valor){
  echo "<br />- ". $campo ." = ". $valor;
}
```

Vi como imprimia hasta x31x4, como en todos los intentos anteriores. Luego agrege mas valores para que pasaran por al otro php por `POST`:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='hola1' value ='hola1'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='hola2' value ='hola2'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='hola3' value ='hola3'>";
```

Y me di cuenta de que imprimia hasta 'x31x1', es decir, **3 valores menos que antes.**
Ahora debo averiguar como hacer que pasen todos por el `POST`

Comment: Tu script pasa por algún equipo de seguridad? Esos son los que filtran el número de parámetros o el tamaño del mensaje...

Comment: max_input_vars esta seteado como 1000, eso es lo que debo cambiar.

Comment: @Krieger me lo apunto!